# data-remote="true" on("ajax:complete" not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

This is on my rails html.erb page

```
<a data-remote="true" data-type="json" href="/project/4/request_access">Request Access</a>
```

This is in my javascript on the same page

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("body").on("ajax:complete", function(e) {
    console.log("Got Ajax complete: ");
    console.log(e);
  });
}
```

I get a 200 success back in my terminal. I get the data in the response I'm looking for, but the console log is never called. I was more specific with an id before, but went to 'body' just to catch everything. It's still not working. What's wrong?

Network Response:

```
General
  Request Method:GET
  Status Code:200 OK
Request Headers
  Accept:application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
  X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Response
  {"success":"You have been added to Y-find"}
```

Comment: Please show the code, where you issue the ajax call.

Comment: can you past your chrome console screenshot if possible?

Comment: Does RoR use jQuery to send its ajax requests? Is the request sent and completed before or after your code runs?

Comment: $("body").on("ajax:complete", function(e)  => $(document).on("ajax:complete", function(e) {

Comment: This is the ajax call. data-remote="true" calls ajax in rails. Why the downvote...

Comment: Yes RoR uses jQuery to send ajax requests. The request is sent upon clicking the link. @abhijit, javascript please.

Comment: None of the suggestions or answers worked. I ended up just having to create an on('click', function($.ajax({  method to handle the ajax requests and callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

You may try it this way:

```
<a id="remote" data-remote="true" data-type="json" href="/project/4/request_access">Request Access</a>


$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#remote").on("ajax:success", function (e, data, status, xhr) {
        console.log( xhr.responseText )

     });
    $("#remote").on("ajax:error", function(e, xhr, status, error) {
        console.log ("ERROR");
    });
});
```

Comment: it should be $("#remote") ?

Comment: All you did was add an ID, and as mentioned in the question I said I was more specific ealier, but opened it up to "body" to catch all ajax. Also you forgot to convert coffee to js on your ajax:error (you need function and parentheses)

Comment: Have a look at the function parameters and you may see the difference: You: `function(e) {
    console.log("Got Ajax complete: ");`, Me: `function (e, data, status, xhr) {
        console.log( xhr.responseText )`

Comment: This is outdated! Look here: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#form-with